# rundll32.exe constantly running taking up resources slowing down my Win 7 computer

Tags: windows, performance, rundll32.exe

Over the past week, my Windows 7 Home Premium computer (8gb RAM, 64bit) has been running slowly. When I look at my processes, there are always 2 rundll32.exe's running taking up 3 & 25% CPU power, memory slowly creeping upwards from around 115mb to 160mb each in the time it has taken me to right this message, sometimes popping upt o 300mb and back down. Svchost.exe is at 260mb.

When I end those processes, everything returns to snappiness.

I recently did some Windows Updates, and I think it was around the time my computer started acting slowly, but I can't remember if it was before or after the updates that things started running slowly. Last night I ccleaned & defrag'ed.

How can I diagnose what's causing the slowness?

Comment: You first need to work out what DLLs they're actually running. In Task Manager: View, Select Columns, Command Line.

Comment: Did you try a virus scan? It's a long shot, but i would definetly give it a try.

Comment: reinstall windows

Comment: I thought I fixed this, but apparently not. Here's complete info from the Command Line in Task Manager:

rundll32.exe C:\Windows\system32\inetcpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 10554

There are 2 of those running, taking up 150K+ memory & 10% CPU. They seem to run after I use something with Audio &/or Video, e.g., Zune, GoToMeeting, Pandora, but I can't pin it down to any one application.

Comment: PS, I ran a virus scan (Norton & Panda), but nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals. This will give you a lot more info about the processes than the Task Manager will. You should be able to deduce what the processes are tied to from there.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be suprised if there is something malicious attatched to the process, look more into it with the aforementioned process explorer and it would be a good idea to run a virus scanner that's not already installed.  I recommend temporarily using panda cloud antivirus.